# a principal homogeneous space is in the trivial class iff it has a point in $\mathbb{Q} ?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is an elliptic curve. So clearly $E$ is a principal homogeneous space for $E$. Now I'm getting trouble to understand this statement saying, **any other principal homogeneous space is in the same class of $E$ iff it has a point in $\mathbb{Q}$.** Could anyone please explain this ?

Comment: Hint: try to convince yourself that if $X$ has a rational point then chasing the $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$-equivariant isomorphism $E_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}\to X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ (focusing on the image of the point $x\in X(\mathbb{Q})$ shows that you're really just looking at the automorphism of $E_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ that comes from translation by a $\mathbb{Q}$-point, which is a rational automorphism, and thus the isomorphism $X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}\cong E_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ is defined rationally.

Comment: This is much easier, by the way, if you know the fact that $G$-torsors (over $\text{Spec}(k)$) are classified by $H^1(G_k,G(\overline{k}))$. Your question then follows from the explicit construction of this equivalence.